# Schlussformel für Beschwerdebrief?

Tags: salutation, formality, letter, valediction

> **Diese Frage wurde auch hier (auf Englisch) beantwortet:**
>   [How to end a complaint letter in German](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/24696/1224)

Standardschlussformel für förmliche Briefe ist ja „Mit freundlichen Grüßen“.

Wenn ich nun aber einen förmlichen Beschwerdebrief schreibe, der nicht wirklich „freundlich“ gemeint ist (weil ich wirklich sauer bin) – gibt es eine passende förmliche Schlussformel?

Ich will nicht unhöflich wirken, aber auch nicht freundlich.

Comment: Ich habe mal einen Beschwerdebrief geschrieben, _bei dem ich mir ohnehin keine Reaktion erhoffen konnte_. Den habe ich so beendet: "Mit der Ihnen und Ihrem Hause gebührenden Hochachtung,". Danach habe ich mich besser gefühlt, aber ich würde es nie tun, wenn ich auf ein gutes Ergebnis hoffe.

Comment: @Hendrik bei uns geht sowas fast immer mit "Hochachtungsvoll, ..." raus

Comment: "Mit freundlichen Grüßen" ist eine **Floskel** und völlig bedeutungsneutral. Du drückst damit *nicht* aus, dass du dem Empfänger des Briefes freundlich gesonnen bist, sondern einzig und allein, dass du dich höflich verhältst. Und das sollte man auch in einem Beschwerdebrief. Deine Unzufriedenheit hast du im Brief selbst zum Ausdruck gebracht.

Comment: Dazu ein Kommentar aus meiner Berufspraxis als kommunaler Stadtplaner, der daher auch mit Beschwerdebriefen zu tun hat: Derjenige, der das fragliche Schreiben liest und bearbeitet, hat in der Regel herzlich wenig Einfluss auf den Tatbestand, über den du dich beschwerst, ist aber in der Situation dennoch (emotional) der Adressat. Daher von mir definitive Zustimmung zu @whats Kommentar.

Comment: Wenn du bis zu diesem Punkt in deinem Brief deine Unzufriedenheit noch nicht zum Ausdruck gebracht hast, wirst due es auch mit einer unhöflichen Schlußformel nicht schaffen....

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Eine explizite Formel für diesen Fall ist mir nicht bekannt.
In der Vergangenheit habe ich bei Beschwerden jedoch trotzdem die reguläre Formel "Mit freundlichen Grüßen" angewendet. Man kann sie auch variieren oder ergänzen, z.B.

> Mit freundlichen Grüßen und in Erwartung [einer Verbesserung, baldigen/zügigen Antwort etc.]
>
> Mit freundlichen Grüßen und auf eine schnelle Klärung des Vorfalls hoffend

Es ist ja formell ebenso korrekt "Sehr geehrter Herr X" zu schreiben, selbst wenn man denjenigen verachtet. Ich würde mir hier keine Blöße geben; wenn sich jemand bei mir schriftlich beschweren sollte (was bis dato nicht vorkam (; ), würde ich trotzdem die Form gewahrt sehen wollen. Wenn du wirklich herausstellen willst, wie sauer du bist, kannst du natürlich auch von z.B. verärgerten Grüßen schreiben oder die Formel auf "Gruß" verkürzen. Alternativ kann man auch auf die Formel verzichten, zum Beispiel:

> In Erwartung einer schnellen Klärung,
>
> Name

Hier wird durch Verzicht auf den Gruß die Verärgerung betont. Du kannst auch jeglichen Schluss weglassen und nur mit deinem Namen den Brief beenden. Das ist im Zweifel weniger unhöflich als eine verärgerte Formel, wenngleich ebenso deutlich.

Die Dringlichkeit und Verärgerung, die deiner Beschwerde zugrunde liegt, würde ich lieber deutlich im eigentlichen Beschwerdetext zur Sprache bringen.

Comment: Hab mal unter einer Beschwerde "Herzliche Grüße" gelesen, muss ja nicht immer Gutes von Herzen kommen ... da kam halt der Frust von Herzen ;-)

Comment: Niemals mit einem Komma nach der Formel! Das ist ein Auswanderer aus dem angelsächsischen Raum, aber im Deutschen falsch!

Ich würde es zu einem "Mit freundlichem Gruß" reduzieren. Oder eben noch "Mit Bitte um Klärung".

Comment: @bot47: Das stimmt, wenn der Gruß abgesetzt ist. Geht der Brieftext jedoch in den Gruß über, stehen reguläre Satzzeichen. Das ist in meinem Beispiel natürlich nicht der Fall, und wenn, wäre es auch kein Komma. Deine Alternativen kannst du übrigens gerne als separate Antwort posten.

Answer (score 31):

Als Faustregel gilt:
Je aggressiver der Inhalt, desto höflicher sollte die Form sein.

"Mit freundlichen Grüßen" ist eine distanzierte Standardformel, die ich nur in Beschwerdebriefen und Amtsverkehr verwende.

(Ansonsten gibt es von mir "Mit herzlichen Grüßen", "Schöne Grüße" oder sogar "Liebe Grüße".)

In einem Beschwerdebrief "verbleibe ich in Hoffnung auf baldige positive Erledigung mit freundlichen Grüßen".

Das Ziel ist nicht, den Adressaten zu beleidigen, sondern etwas zu erreichen, z. B., dass er mir mein Geld zurückgibt.

Wenn du den Adressaten in erster Linie beleidigen willst, dann gibt es natürlich noch ganz andere Möglichkeiten.

Comment: +1 für den Tipp, sich darüber klar zu werden, ob man etwas erreichen oder den anderen beleidigen will. Über Beleidigungen im Deutschen könnte man vermutlich problemlos [ein Buch](http://www.amazon.de/Die-Kunst-Beleidigung-Hans-Raeth/dp/3771643511) schreiben.

Comment: Das wirkt für mich eher passiv-aggressiv. Wenn man eine saftige Beschwerde schreibt, muss man da nicht noch Honig um den Mund schmieren.

Comment: @infinitezero Es ist üblich und höflich. Höflichkeit hat immer einen passiv-aggressiven Aspekt, wird aber schlicht und einfach von den meisten Leuten erwartet. Und eine Beschwerde ist eben nicht immer der Versuch, seine negative Stimmung auszudrücken, sondern etwas Konkretes zu erreichen.

Answer (score 9):

Meine Empfehlung wäre es, auch für einen **förmlichen** Beschwerdebrief die Standardanrede und Standardschlussformel zu wählen.

> Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,
>
> Mit freundlichen Grüßen

Alles andere ist meines Erachtens nicht nur unfreundlich, sondern auch kontraproduktiv. Allenfalls kann man sich überlegen, nur einen singulären Gruß zu senden:

> Mit freundlichem Gruß

Comment: +1, weil ich das im Prinzip genauso sehe. Aber ich kann auch verstehen, wenn einem die Formeln "zu wenig" sind und man daher variieren möchte, auch wenn ich davon abraten würde :)

Answer (score 9):

#### Entweder - oder

Wenn es förmlich sein soll, 'Mit freundlichen Grüßen'.

Wenn nicht, dann geht alles.

- von subtilen Kursivitäten:

  Mit *freundlichen* Grüßen, Schulz
- über gar keine Grüße - einfach den Namen drunter 'Maier'
- verspielten 'mit weniger freundlichen Grüßen, Müller'
- sachlicher Trockenheit: 'nachhaltig verärgert, Wagner'
- bis zu übler Beleidigung: 'Sie aufgedunsenes ****gesicht, kaufen Sie sich einen Strick! Schmitt'
- Die Eskalationsstufe 'Briefbombe' sollte man vorher gründlich überlegen, und mit dem pers. Anwalt und Therapeuten erörtern. Lieber einen Tag abwarten, und dann nochmal nachdenken. Spätestens die Überlegung der Gefahr, dass ein unbeteiligter Dritter die Post öffnet sollte einen davon abbringen.

Comment: +1 wegen der konzisen Zusammenfassung und... dem herrlichen Schluss.

Comment: Ich habe auch schon
"Mit (noch) freundlichen Grüßen"
gelesen ...

Answer (score 7):

> Hochachtungsvoll

... ist höflich, aber nicht freundlich.

Comment: Ich glaube nicht, dass der Fragesteller/die Fragestellerin Respekt ausdrücken möchte.

Comment: @Carlster Ich erinnere mich vor einiger Zeit in der Wikipedia zum Thema [Grußformeln](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hochachtungsvoll#Gru.C3.9Fformeln_f.C3.BCr_Gesch.C3.A4ftsbriefe) folgendes gefunden zu haben: "bedeutend ist, dass in diesen Formeln bewusst kein (freundlicher) Gruß mehr ausgesprochen wird, sondern als letzte Wahrung der Form lediglich ein Ausspruch der Achtung, d.h. des Respekts vor dem Korrespondenzpartner erfolgt". Eine mögliche Steigerung wäre laut Artikel noch "mit vorzüglicher Hochachtung", hilfreich ist die damit ausgedrückte Form von Sarkasmus allerdings nicht.

Comment: Respekt schon, aber "Hochachtung" scheint mir für jemanden, auf den man sauer ist, zu viel zu sein.

Comment: Ich hatte immer den Eindruck, dass Hochachtungsvoll so altbacken ist, dass hiermit kein Respekt mehr ausgedrueckt wird, sondern das Gegenteil. Bin aber seit 12 Jahren nicht mehr in Deutschland, vielleicht hat sich das veraendert?

Comment: nein, @jdog, dein Eindruck trügt nicht. Es ist so altbacken, dass es kaum noch Leute gibt, die *"Hochachtungsvoll"* schreiben. Die *"freundlichen Grüße"* sind auch im Beschwerdebrief üblich.

Comment: _Hochachtungsvoll_ passt deswegen, weil es formal höflich ist und gleichzeitig so übertrieben (in dem Kontext), daß der Leser es garnicht ernst nehmen kann sondern sich verspottet fühlen dürfte. Wenn man genau das erreichen will, ist _hochachtungsvoll_ super. Wenn man hingegen noch die Hoffnung auf eine gütliche Einigung haben sollte, würde ich es daher nicht verwenden.

Comment: Genau die richtige Wahl. Wird generell auch gerne unmittelbar vor der nächsten Eskalationsstufe verwendet.

Answer (score 4):

Für Österreich kann ich sagen, dass "Hochachtungsvoll" sehr formelhaft ist, und nicht per se besonders freundlich, aber auch nicht besonders respektvoll. "Mit dem Ausdruck vorzüglicher Hochachtung" ist schon sarkastisch, wird aber bisweilen durchaus verwendet.

Comment: "Mit vorzüglicher Hochachtung" war früher durchaus üblich, wird aber heute kaum noch verwendet. Ein entfernter Bekannter entfremdete das gelegentlich zu "Mit vorzüglicher Missachtung".

Comment: Ist halt die Frage, ob man sich auf dieses Niveau herablassen will. Es ist schon hart an der Grenze zur Ehrenrührigkeit und dem eigenen, seriösen Anliegen eher nicht dienlich.

Comment: Natürlich ist das beleidigend und kontraproduktiv. Die "Grußformel" war auch nicht als Empfehlung gedacht, sondern rein anekdotisch.

Answer (score 1):

Ich schließe in diesen Fällen schlicht mit

> "Grüße"

Bei

> "Grüße!"

ist es besonders heftig (**!**), doch der Anstand gebietet eine Schussfloskel

Answer (score 0):

Ich setzte als letztes Wort im Text "verbleibend" ein und mache einen Punkt.
Dann folgt das übliche "Mit freundlichen Grüßen,".
Also liest man: verbleibend mit freundlichen Grüßen. Das drückt klar aus das ich nur der Form zuliebe freundlich bleibe, freundliche Grüsse sind das aber nicht.

Liebe Grüße,
Jens

Answer (score 0):

Das bereits erwähnte "Hochachtungsvoll" ist - auch das kam schon in anderen Antworten zur Sprache - durchaus formell und *nichts, woraus man einen Strick drehen könnte*. In der Kunst der subtilen Beleidigung geht es unter anderem ja auch darum, dafür zu sorgen, daß sich die Beleidigung nicht auf dem Papier sondern in den Gedanken des Lesenden abspielt: jeder kann sich denken, was gemeint ist, aber *dastehen tut's nicht*!

Darüber hinaus gebe ich zu bedenken, daß formelhafte Wendungen sowieso nicht wirklich als ernstgemeint aufgefaßt werden: wenn man in der Anrede als "Sehr geehrte(r)" angesprochen wird, dann geht man auch nicht automatisch davon aus, der Schreiber glaube, man sei mit Ehrungen überhäuft. Auch sagt man "Guten Tag" selbst zu Leuten, denen man nichts weniger als einen *guten* Tag wünscht.

Insofern ist es meiner unmaßgeblichen Meinung nach ziemlich unerheblich, welche Gruß*formel* man verwendet. "Hochachtungsvoll" oder "mit vorzüglicher Hochachtung" kann mindestens durch die offensichtlich übertriebene Förmlichkeit und Höflichkeit für den Transport der intendierten Bedeutung sorgen.

Noch ein Gesichtspunkt: abhängig davon, wen man anschreibt, kann es sinnvoll sein, auf - auch subtile - Beleidigungen zu verzichten. Falls einem der Angeschriebene persönlich bekannt ist, kann die Beleidigung ihren Zweck haben (und erreichen), falls der Adressat die Schadensregulierungsstelle einer Versicherung oder der Kundendienst eines Großunternehmens ist, kann sich jeder selbst die Frage stellen, ob er einen ahnungslosen Sachbearbeiter, der zufällig den zehnten Brief in einer leidigen Angelegenheit vom Ticketsystem zugeteilt bekommt, wirklich beleidigen möchte. Vermutlich kennt der Beleidigte weder die Vorgeschichte, noch war er an ihr beteiligt.

Answer (score 0):

Versuchs doch mit "Mit den Ihnen gebührenden Grüßen" oder "Mit der Ihnen gebührenden Hochachtung"