# How to end a complaint letter in German

Tags: formality, salutation, letter, valediction

> **This question also has an answer here (in German):**
>   *[Schlussformel für Beschwerdebrief?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1665/schlussformel-f%c3%bcr-beschwerdebrief)*

I am writing a complaint letter and want to know how to end it. The issue was pretty bad and I'm very unsatisfied/offended with the service, so does "Mit freundlichen Grüßen" sound ironic? (I'm definitely not *freundlich* in the letter).

Is there something more neutral like the English *Regards* or *Sincerely*?

Comment: the linked thread has all the relevant answers. you may indeed say `Mit freundlichen Grüßen` or `Freundliche Grüße` or `Hochachtungsvoll`. While your letter may sound unfriendly it is important to not be offending.

Comment: This should not have been closed. There is consensus that questions in one language can't be duplicates of questions in the other language.

Comment: Reopened: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/807/what-to-do-when-the-asker-cannot-understand-the-duplicate-question-due-to-it-bei

Comment: Once I also wrote a complaint letter, and ended it with »mit Grüßen«, so I just omitted the obligatory »freundlichen«. I guess the message was clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking it is not a good advice to be offending or harsh in a letter. Even an unfriendly letter, even if deserved, is not something one would advise you to write.

To answer your question whether it sounds ironic: no, it does not. It's okay to tease a bit, but you should be able to convey you very bad opinion with neutral (or not offending) words.

However, you can end your letter with

> Freundliche Grüße
>   Mit freundlichen Grüßen
>   Hochachtungsvoll

At least, those are most common. If you want, you can just write down your name without any greeting phrase.

Comment: Today *Hochachtungsvoll* is no longer in use. It may only occasionally still be seen in letters from old to very old people (80+).

Comment: I'm 24 and I complain all the time - always hochachtungsvolly ;-)

Comment: On this matter there is [a nice article on Knigge.de](http://www.knigge.de/archiv/ihre-fragen/im-beruf---mfg-oder-hochachtungsvoll-11196.htm) (not to be taken too seriously). There also is a [summary on Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gru%C3%9Fformel_%28Korrespondenz%29) where "Hochachtung" would still be appropriate... not that I want to correct you, but it may be preceived different to the intention you had in your letters of complaint ;)